# Python in Terminal groupby returning only NaN with multiple columns instead of 1

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I am running the following code of python in a terminal:

```
df_null_count_extract['DAY_AVG'] = df_null_count_extract.groupby(['CONTROL_COL_NAME', 'RUN_ID', 'RUN_DATE', 'CONTROL_TABLE_NAME'], as_index = False)['CONTROL_COL_VAL'].transform('mean')
```

When I do however I only receive NaN values and it returns multiple instead of one

```
print(df_null_count_extract.groupby(['CONTROL_COL_NAME', 'RUN_ID', 'RUN_DATE', 'CONTROL_TABLE_NAME'], as_index = False)['CONTROL_COL_VAL'].transform('mean'))
```

[image: Null Return]

The expected results would simply be to add the transform.mean() results to the df_null_count_extract df, this works perfectly well in Jupyter but not in the terminal.

I have tried changing the format of the code, but it does not yield any results. If I replace df_null_count_extract['DAY_AVG'] = 100 for testing it completes the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, terminal did not like the as_index = False after I removed that it worked perfectly